# Output json stringify elements

Tags: json, typescript

I have a problem. I am using `TypeScript` and I get a response back. I want to output the information. How could I output e.g. `internalCompanyCode` and `timestamp`.

What I got

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.(
```

```
//const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
// json is the result of JSON.stringify(...)
const json = [
  {
    "internalCompanyCode": "007",
    "moreInfo": [
      {
        "dimensions": {
          "height": 27,
          "width": 31,
          "length": 61
        },
        "currenStatus": {
          "arrived": {
            "timestamp": "10:00:12"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(json['internalCompanyCode'])
console.log(json['moreInfo']['dimensions']['height'])
```

Comment: You can't just skip layers of your data structure. You have an array. You have to get the object you want out of the array. You can't just pretend the array is your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data you don't have to stringify result. You have to use result  before stringifying to json or have to parse json back to result if you did it

```
console.log(result[0]['internalCompanyCode']) //007

console.log(result[0]['moreInfo'][0]['currenStatus']['arrived']['timestamp']) // 10:00:12

console.log(result[0]['moreInfo'][0]['dimensions']['height']) //27
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `json` object is actually a list so you will have to access it like `json[0]['internalCompanyCode']`

Comment: Thank you. And how do I get `width` and `timestamp`?

Comment: your `moreInfo` also starts with brackets, therefore its an array too. so you can access it with `json[0]['moreInfo'][0][...]`